# Use what you know: Your take on Diceware

Tags: code-golf, random

If you're not familiar, [Diceware](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diceware) is a method for creating passwords using an ordinary die from a pair of dice as a hardware random number generator.

For the sake of fun, let's ignore anything about the security of computer's random number generators.

Write a function or program that prints or returns a single five-character string containing a random selection of the numbers 1 through 6. These should be chosen with equal probability.

Example valid outputs:

```
21321
14654
53552
63641
```

No standard loopholes! This is code-golf, so shortest code in bytes wins.

Comment: [Like this?](http://xkcd.com/221/)

Comment: @PeterTaylor - the question you marked this a duplicate of is not  even close to the same. Please unmark the question as a duplicate.

Comment: It's replacing an is-zero test with a loop. That's a trivial change, and by the standards of this site qualifies as a duplicate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Dyalog APL, 7 bytes

```
10⊥?5⍴6
```

Try it online on [TryAPL](http://tryapl.org/?a=10%u22A5%3F5%u23746&run).

#### How it works

```
    5⍴6  Yield (6 6 6 6)
   ?     Roll; turn each 6 into a random integer between 1 and 6.
10⊥      Decode with base 10.
```

Answer (score 1):

## Julia, 24 bytes

```
print(join(rand(1:6,5)))
```

We use `rand` to get an array of length five consisting of elements randomly chosen from the range 1:6. We join it into a string using `join` then print it to STDOUT using `print`.

Answer (score 1):

### J, 11 bytes

```
a.{~49+?5$6
```

Explanation:

```
        5$6    NB. repeat 6 five times      output: 6 6 6 6 6
       ?5$6    NB. 5 random integers < 6    output: 4 5 1 0 2
    49+?5$6    NB. add 49 ('1') to them     output: 53 54 50 49 51
a.{~49+?5$6    NB. convert them to ASCII    output: 56213
```

Answer (score 0):

## [TeaScript](http://github.com/vihanb/teascript), 11 bytes

```
r6)ΣN6))j(u
```

[Try it online](http://vihan.org/p/TeaScript/#?code=%22r6)%CE%A3N6))j(u%22&inputs=%5B%22%22%5D&opts=%7B%22int%22:false,%22ar%22:false,%22debug%22:true%7D)

Answer (score 0):

## Pyth, <s>9</s> 8 bytes

```
jkO^S6 5
```

[Try it online.](http://pyth.herokuapp.com/?code=jkO%5ES6+5&debug=0)

Get list of numbers 1 to 6, Cartesian 5<sup>th</sup> power, pick random element, join by empty string.

Answer (score 0):

### CJam, 8 bytes

```
{6mr)}5*
```

[Test it here.](http://cjam.aditsu.net/#code=%7B6mr)%7D5*)

#### Explanation

```
{       e# Run this block 5 times.
   6mr  e# Get a random integer in [0,5] with uniform distribution.
   )    e# Increment.
}5*
```

Answer (score 0):

## Mathematica, 36 bytes

```
""<>ToString/@{1,6}~RandomInteger~5&
```

*cough cough* string formatting *cough cough*

Answer (score 0):

## MATLAB / Octave, 12 bytes

```
[49+6*rand(1,6),'']
ans = 153361
```

`rand(x,y)` creates a random array with dimensions `(x-by-y)` with numbers between `0` and `1`. Multiply this by 6 to get values between 0 and 6. Add `49` to get a value `49 < n < 55` (the random number will never be exactly 0 or 1). `[...,'']` converts this to strings with the floored values of n (integers `[49 54]` corresponding to `[1 6]` in ASCII.